# how to filter a line using multiple column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet here that has 3 columns, and below each column lots of text.

How can create a filter that I can find all occurrences of a given text in any of these columns and show only the lines that has it no matter the column that it has been found.

Comment: Excel can't do this type of filter, one workaround can be to create a helper column where you concatenate content of the other columns and filter there.

Comment: I tried to select the entire sheet and apply a custom filter but did not find how to apply the rule the other column than the one that is selected.

Comment: Ok, I did this and works nicely. Now how can I create something like a search box and apply it to the filter automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I just did was create a filter and a macro to set the filter as the value of a certain cell.

follows the code I copied from the internet and changed a little bit.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iFilterColumn As Integer
    Dim rFilter As Range
    Dim sCriteria As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With Target
        Set rFilter = .Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        iFilterColumn = .Column + 1 - rFilter.Columns(1).Column
        If Intersect(Target, Range("rCriteria")) Is Nothing Then GoTo Terminator
        Select Case Left(.Value, 1)
        Case ">", "<"
            sCriteria = .Value
        Case Else
            sCriteria = "=*" & .Value & "*"
        End Select
        If sCriteria = "=" Then
            .Parent.Range(rFilter.Address).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterColumn
        Else
            .Parent.Range(rFilter.Address).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterColumn, Criteria1:=sCriteria
        End If
    End With
Terminator:
    Set rFilter = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```